# Where do I find this Advanced scaling settings menu in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, windows-11-v22h2

In Windows 10 there is a menu where it's possible to enable Fixing the scaling for apps.

[image]

I cannot find this in Windows 11 unfortunately.

Some of the apps I use need this function to work correctly.

Thanks

Comment: There isn’t an equivalent option within Settings on Windows 11

Comment: Windows 11 - Settings, Display for basic options. Search for Calibrate Display Color which includes Display crispness at the end.  Make sure your display enlargement is at 100% or one of the offered enlargements - not 113% or such like. Make sure text size is at 100% for testing.

Answer (score 0):

As of at least 22621, there isn't an equivalent feature. But, you can define a custom scale here:

System > Display > Custom Scaling (click on scaling)

You might have success running the ClearType wizard to fix blurry text. Open the start menu and type 'ClearType'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/cleartype/